# I need a simple way to avoid callback nests in javascript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback

I have a NPAPI plugin that I changed to native messaging, NPAPI is synchronous and so was the plugin.  since chrome ditched NPAPI for good

Now that I have to change it to asynchronous calls, I am trying to find a way to handle the callbacks . I have wrapped the messaging into a class to handle a specific message from content script to background script.

I am handling the callbacks inside the class through setting it to internal array of callbacks functions as well as function specific result callbacks

However I am find difficulty in changing page code

as an example
lets assume the old code was like

```
 res = npClass.function1 (var1,var2);
   if(res == 'someval')
     npClass.function2()
   npClass.function1(var2,res.substring(2,3))
 and so on
```

now that all functions are async I have to change the code to be more or less like this

```
    npClass.function1(var1,var2, function(res)
          {
              if(res == 'someval')
                 npClass.function2(function(){
                              npClass.function1(var2,res.substring(2,3), function(res)
{});
npClass.function1(var2,res.substring(2,3);

                    }
          }
```

and the nesting will go on and on this isn't how I expect it to be.

All I can think of is right now is that may be if I change the page code to make the parts of code that uses the extension as a class that inherits from the other message handling class then I can use the internal structure to invoke callbacks on the new class callbacks in messaging class

But even if I do this my code will be very fragmented

it will be something like this

```
PageClass.prototype.functionL()
{
    functions1(functionb) 'from inheritance
}
PageClass.functionb(res)
{
   if(res == 'some value)
     function2( functionq) 'from inheritance
}
```

Still this is not suitable for me and I am sure I will have to handle a lot of stuff in it plus this will require a huge change in the structure of the page code.

I have searched all around to find any way to make async call sync in javascript but didn't find any plausible solution.

I am not expert in javascript and I need ideas to explore,
can someone here guide me

Comment: You can use ES7 async await or generators with [babel](https://babeljs.io/docs/learn-es2015/).

Comment: start with reasonable indentation, that would make it much more readable :-)

Comment: You're looking for promises.

Comment: I tried promises but as far as my understanding promises will serve the same as inheriting the class itself .. it doesn't make asynchronous code synchronous but help to call a function even if the caller is out of scope

Comment: ES7 is supported with which chrome version?

Comment: Well there is no magic to make asynchronous code synchronous. In the best case, you can make it look synchronous but that's the best you can hope for. ES7 helps with its `async functions`. Support in browser can be found here : http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es7/ . You will see support are far from universal though `async` is supported in chrome.

Comment: Generators could also help make your code look more sync (while adding the keyword `yield` and some other syntactic details). They can be found in ES6 so you have more luck here. The same link with es6 instead of es7 will give you the browser compatibility table. But what's wrong with promises? It works perfectly fine for your use case, and it is well supported in most browsers, and it is the easiest notion to master of all mentioned before. You should read about it again.

Comment: Your code is not easy to understand but you should get to something like that : `npClass.function1 (var1,var2).then (function(res){if(res == 'someval') return /*your code here which returns a promise*/ else return /*your code here which returns a promise*/}).then (function(res){/*finish your processing here*/})`.

Comment: I have read about promises , correct me if I am wrong, the res value will only be valid if the promise resolved .. i.e. in the .then function i.e. I have to make another promise inside the .then